# Parse's REST API and PHP Curl error : {"code":201,"error":"missing user password"}

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, parse-platform

I am getting user password missing error even i an using urlencode .. i have read many solutions also but couldn't resolve it .i am using form to get data from user and then use curl to create the user .
plzz help

here's my code

$data = array();

```
    $data['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $data['mobile'] = $_POST['mobile'];
    $data['password'] =  $_POST['password'];
    $data['email'] = $_POST['email']; 

    $post_str = '';

   foreach($data as $key=>$val) 
        {
            $post_str .= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($val).'&';
        }
        echo $post_str = substr($post_str, 0, -1);


 $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/users';  

 $appId = 'apikey';  
 $restKey = 'rest key';  
 $headers = array(  
   "Content-Type: application/json",  
   "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,  
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey  
 );  


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_str) );

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the provided Parse PHP SDK https://github.com/parseplatform/parse-php-sdk?

In your code you should not try to `urlencode()` the data, just pass it as array to `json_encode()`:

```
<?php
// ...
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```